# Find Minimum Number of Days Between Events in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, ansi-sql

Let's say I have the following table and, for each player, I want to know the smallest gap (number of days) possible between playing game `A` and game `B`. Note that the order doesn't matter (i.e., you could play `A` followed by `B` OR `B` followed by `A`).

| Player | Date | Game |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-10 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-06 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-07 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-08 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-05 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-08 | B |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 | B |
| 4 | 2021-01-02 | B |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 | A |
| 4 | 2021-01-07 | B |

So, the expected output would be:

| Player | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |

I know that I'll need to perform a `group-by` and `order-by`:

```
SELECT DO_SOMETHING
FROM PLAY_TABLE
GROUP BY PLAYER
ORDER BY DATE
```

For each group, it looks like I need to take the difference in `DATE` when neighboring rows have different `GAME` values and then return the minimum but it's not clear to me how to accomplish this.

Comment: Perhaps a self join?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Are there ever more than two games?  *(Can there be a game `C`?)*  Can two games, or the same or different types, ever be played on the same day?  Does the `Date` column always only contain a date, or can/does it also contain a time component?

Comment: The `Date` column is always only a date. You can assume that it is always only game `A` and game `B`. Also, more than one game can be played on the same day (either all of `A`, all of `B`, or a mix of `A` and `B` in the same day)!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest gap will be on adjacent rows, so you can use `lag()`.

```
select player, min(date - prev_date)
from (select t.*,
             lag(game) over (partition by player order by date) as prev_game,
             lag(date) over (partition by player order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_game = 'A' and game = 'B' or
      prev_game = 'B' and game = 'A'
group by player;
```

Note that date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent, so `-` might not work in your database.